# add region with module installation

Tags: 7, theming

I am developing a module, that when installed, should place an HTML element in a drupal block.
That block, will be inside a region. I would like the region to be added to the theme on module installation. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you **cant** create custom region in a theme using custom module in a drupal way . however you can [fetch available regions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_region_list/6)